# Problems with MAILTO setting: server doesn't sent cron's e-mail

Tags: 14.04, email, cron

I have Ubuntu 14.04 with Postfix mail server. Php/apache can send e-mails.

But I don't receive any messages from cron. Here's my setup:

```
MAILTO=myname@email.com
*/2 * * * * wget -o /home/user/out.html http://example.com/crontab
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh, I found the answer!

I should have used big `-O` to mean "output file", but instead I used small `-o` which means "output log", so, no log for cron, nothing to send - no emails!